# Help finding a Bandcamp downloader

Tags: 20.04

Does anybody know of a Bandcamp downloader for Ubuntu?

I have tried Pi-Yi but got no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are looking for an easier way to check out an album and intend to pay for it if you like it (which you really should, because artist move off of Bandcamp when people don't). In that case `bandcamp-dl` works quite well, you can install the most recent version using:

```
pip3 install bandcamp-downloader
```

It takes the album URL as an argument and downloads it to `$HOME/ARTIST/ALBUM` by default. It is usually more convenient to download it to some other location, e.g. the Music folder, which can be specified with the `--base-dir=` argument:

```
bandcamp-dl --base-dir=${HOME}/Music/ $URL
```

Comment: Nope didn't work

Comment: @CJUK Can you eaborate on that?

Answer (score 0):

MediaHuman's YouTubeToMP3 will do the trick without using scripts.   Just make sure to watch the tutorial.   Should just auto detect your links.

https://www.mediahuman.com/howto/bandcamp-to-mp3.html